# How to select data of a table from another database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linked-server

Suppose that I have a database which name is `testdb` in **test server**.
I also have a database named **proddb** in **prod** server.

Now I want to select data of a table of **testdb** database from **proddb** database.

How can I do that in **`SQL Server`**?

Also, I can do it using **database link** in **oracle**. But how can do that in **SQL Server**?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 or above, jump down to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41127437/733092.

Comment: This same topic has been discussed also in https://stackoverflow.com/q/3788566/1548275

Answer (score 72):

You need sp_addlinkedserver()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Example:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'test'
```

then

```
select * from [server].[database].[schema].[table]
```

In your example:

```
select * from [test].[testdb].[dbo].[table]
```

Comment: If you need to pass through different credentials, use EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'servername', 'false', NULL, 'SqlUser', 'password'

Comment: I was struggling to get this to work, found you can also do this using SSMS (https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/)  which then shows you all the various security etc options that are available - i found i had to set set it to use the current logins security context to get it to work.

Answer (score 54):

In SQL Server 2012 and above, you don't need to create a link. You can execute directly

```
SELECT * FROM [TARGET_DATABASE].dbo.[TABLE] AS _TARGET
```

I don't know whether previous versions of SQL Server work as well

Comment: Doesn't work on Azure. If you need it in Azure, Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715668

Comment: This works in Azure now with the same user in both databases

Answer (score 12):

I've used this before to setup a query against another server and db via linked server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='PWA_ProjectServer', @srvproduct='',
@provider='SQLOLEDB', @datasrc='SERVERNAME\PWA_ProjectServer'
```

per the comment above:

```
select * from [server].[database].[schema].[table]
```

e.g.

```
select top 6 * from [PWA_ProjectServer].[PWA_ProjectServer_Reporting].[dbo].[MSP_AdminStatus]
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio you can create `Linked Server`. First make connection to current (local) server, then go to `Server Objects` > `Linked Servers` > context menu > `New Linked Server`. In window `New Linked Server` you have to specify desired server name for remote server, real server name or IP address (Data Source) and credentials (Security page).

And further you can select data from linked server:

```
select * from [linked_server_name].[database].[schema].[table]
```

Answer (score 5):

To do a cross server query, check out the system stored procedure: **sp_addlinkedserver** in the help files.

Once the server is linked you can run a query against it.

Comment: The tables are in different server.

Comment: How can I link between to servers and how can I select data? please provide steps. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using OPENDATASOURCE
The syntax is like this:

```
select * from OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=192.168.6.69;Initial Catalog=AnotherDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=AnotherDBPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;' ).HumanResources.Department.MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from [Database].[dbo].[TableName]
select * from [dbTest].[dbo].[Products]
```