# Assign a database name into the variable via SQL in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to assign database name into the declared variable and this is how I tried already:

```
DECLARE @DBname VARCHAR(100)

SET @DBname = 'PatientTurningSystem'

SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE
FROM @DBname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_TableDeatails, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'

Comment: You **cannot** pass schema, database, table or column names as a **parameter** - if you want to do this, you must use *dynamic SQL*

Comment: how can I use __dynamic__ SQL for this code?

Comment: If you need to use dynamic SQL then you are doing something wrong. Why would you need it to be dynamic anyway? That is unusual.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Your `@DBName` variable is right now **exactly ONE character** long - so that won't work anyway.... use `DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(100)` or whatever makes sense in your case

Comment: I want to create a procedure that receives a database name as a parameter and give me all of that database tables information.

Comment: i've edited it. ```DECLARE @DBname VARCHAR(100)``` but it has also error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do something like: USE @databaseName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788566/how-can-i-do-something-like-use-databasename)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following query

```
DECLARE @DBname VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DBname = 'PatientTurningSystem'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE
FROM ' +@DBname+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DBname VARCHAR
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(255)

SET @DBname = 'PatientTurningSystem'

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE
FROM '+@DBname+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'

EXEC @QUERY
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me.
this error is:
Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Line 14
Database 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE
FROM PatientTurningSystem' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: First off, the `@DBName` really must have  a  **length** in its declaration - otherwise, this is never going to work. And secondly, the `EXEC` function expects an `NVARCHAR` - so please define your `@Query` to be `NVARCHAR`, and use the `N'....'` prefix when settings its value

Comment: @marc_s since Query should be NVARCHAR, should the Dbname also need to be NVARCHAR as well?

Comment: Just EXEC(@QUERY) will work. Also please declare the @DBName as VARCHAR(255)

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but I use the following script to lookup a database_name and set it as a variable value for use in a downstream activity. In this case, to avoid any errors associated with syntax later on (using AWS RDS db names are bracketed) I added '[]' around the name.

In this case you'll only need to change what the script is looking for `Like '%BCI%'` to your desired value.

```
Declare @DBnameis VARCHAR(30)
Declare @DBname VARCHAR(30)
    
Set @DBnameis = (select [name] as database_name
     from sys.databases
     Where [name] Like '%BCI%')
    
Select @DBnameis
    
Set @DBname = '['+@DBnameis+']'
```