# Can domain name be used on a MySQL url?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a bit concerned about this MySQL URL issue, I just wanted to ask if a MySQL URL could be like this:

mysql://domain.com:3306/database

or does it have to be IP addresses?

Comment: your using mysql for website or what ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a database from another webserver I owned...

Comment: so there is no data exchange between two sql server ....

Comment: There are... Just an example, I use domain1.com to receive and display data from domain2.com but I'm asking is it possible to use the MySQL format like this:

mysql://domain2.com:3306/database

To get the data from domain2.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720339/how-to-select-data-of-a-table-from-another-database-in-sql-server  ... may be it will help

Comment: actually, I am looking for a Database URL format but thank you for that anyway...

Comment: You suggest that you are connecting today using ip address Is that correct? If so, where are you doing this? Is it in some php code or what? Can you share that small part of the code (and you can change the ip address for security if you like)?