# Cross references between data warehouses in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

In one SQL Server instance, I have these 2 data warehouses:

```
sqlwarehouse1 
sqlwarehouse2
```

And in `sqlwarehouse2`, I have a table `dbo.test`.

How can I refer to this table from `sqlwarehouse1`?

Is this cross data warehouse communication possible in Azure SQL data warehouses?

Comment: You would have to configure External Data Sources to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, Could please elaborate on this.. You meant, the table dbo.test should point to an external source like blob and "sqlwarehouse1"  should refer from blob?

Comment: I don't use Azure very often, and when i have, I've never had to do it. There are answers out there though, such as [Not able to do cross database query in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45715668/2029983)

Comment: Can you describe the business goal you are trying to accomplish (not what you want but why)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL DW (now called Azure Synapse Analytics) can’t currently connect to another DW. Polybase currently just reads from files.

You could create a small Azure SQL Database to use to connect to the DWs as follows:

```
 CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pass@word1'; 
 CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL DWCredential 
 WITH IDENTITY = 'usernameHere', 
 SECRET = 'passwordHere';  


 CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE DWDataSource WITH 
    (TYPE = RDBMS, 
    LOCATION = 'yourservername.database.windows.net', 
    DATABASE_NAME = 'yourdw', 
    CREDENTIAL = DWCredential, 
) ;



CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].MyName 
(   [ProductKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductAlternateKey] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](7) NULL) 
WITH 
( DATA_SOURCE = DWDataSource
,SCHEMA_NAME = N'dbo',  
        OBJECT_NAME = N'YourDwTableName') 


select * from MyName



--or run an exact query against SQL DW directly:
exec sp_execute_remote @data_source_name = N'DWDataSource', @stmt  = N'SELECT distinct ModelName from dbo.DimProduct'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg, I will work out this and update here...So the external table in SQL Database, I can call from sqlware house2?

Comment: Hi Greg, 
Using the above solution, I am able to create an external table in SQL data base and query tables in DW1...Now How can I refer an external table in SQL DB from DW2?..I think we achieved half part...Please suggest me the rest

Comment: Microsoft reference are saying Azure SQL DW only supports Blob storage as external data source "https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/587ab9cc-d3ec-4183-9f79-bdacf3cf74d4/unable-to-create-external-table-at-azure-sql-data-warehouse-pointing-to-azure-sql-server?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse"

Comment: One solution found is Export data from DW1 to Blob and import to DW2 as external table from Blob  "https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/analyze/tsql.html"

Comment: `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT` to export to Blob from DW1 and the selecting from an external table in DW2 is certainly the highest bandwidth option if you want to move a large amount of data.

Comment: @Anna you can read from both DWs from your DB. You can’t easily write to DW2 using the DB solution I suggested. It would be a change in your plan if you follow my answer. But thus answer will work well if you need to combine small summarized results from multiple DWs into a DB