# What type of web framework should be used to compare data between databases?

Tags: database, web, backend, web-frameworks, data-comparison

I want to query 2 or more Databases every day at a certain time, compare the resulting data and show the inconsistencies in a web page.

Mainly the data will match through PKs and comparison made using some column values.

So I´m reading about web frameworks like Django, Node, Spring, Rails, etc and wondering if that's what I want. If a REST API is what suits this purpose or if it's something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you compare the data in the database layer and only return the comparison results, so you can show them with any framework.

Comment: How can I compare data in database layer with two different databases?

Comment: Please check the link below whether it satisfies your needs or not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720339/how-to-select-data-of-a-table-from-another-database-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need to focus in the databases that you're going to read, are they SQL/MongoDB/other?

Then think about the website that you're going to build, single page/multiple pages?

Comment: Can be any type of DB. Front-end is in Angular so its SPA